# PHP MySQL Select ID from one table and photo from another

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables in my database. One table contains information about users, while the other contains data about reservations. When a user makes a reservation the userid will be placed in the reservation table. Now I would like to show a photo of the user who has made that reservation, along with the remarks and date of the reservation, but the photo is in the users table.

Here are my two tables:

- Table reservations

> reservationID |
>   userID | 
>   date | 
>   roomtype | 
>   remarks

- Table users

> userID |
>   userlevel |
>   email |
>   password |
>   foto

Comment: learn http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: please use mysql join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I didn't make any syntax errors in my query but here you go:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` LEFT JOIN `reservations` ON (`users`.`userID` = `reservations`.`userID`) WHERE users.userID = [userID here]
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but it doesn't seem to work. Also I would like to show reservations from all users who have made a reservation on a specific roomtype.

Comment: Nevermind I figured it out. Turns out my table name was spelled differently from yours. I was trying to fix this thingy for a few hours now and you just helped me in less than a minute. Thank you very much!

Comment: Heh, I'm glad I could help you! :) Be sure to mark as solution to help others in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can retrieve both table values with this query:

```
SELECT * FROM reservations r 
  JOIN users u ON r.userID = u.userID
 WHERE r.userID = 'your userID'
```